# Working on a simple slider menu, but the menu items are hidden even after slider and page translation

Tags: css

The div tags are nested as

```
<div class="Site-wrapper" id="Site-wrapper">
  <div id="Main-Menu-mobile" class="Main-Menu-mobile">
   <div class="Site">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The logic for the menu is just these 4 CSS classes

```
.Site-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-open .Site {
  left: auto;
  transform: translate3d(70%, 0, 0);
}

.Site {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.Main-Menu-mobile {
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/taufeq-orangejulius-razakh/pen/dypgjNO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Site-Wrapper` div (The parent one) only has a `height` of `41px`. And this stays the same even when the toggler button translates to right. This is where the implementation is a bit off.

Try removing your `overflow:hidden` from .Site-wrapper

```
.Site-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; This needs to be implemented well*/
}
```

What you can do, is once the Hamburger icon is clicked change the overflow property value in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, toggling the overflow property works.